# How to mark posts as edited?

Tags: mysql

I would like to have questions marked as "Edited", but I dont know what the best way to do this would be.

Users post a question, people answer/comment on the question, and if necessary the user edits/updates the question (just like SO). I would like to note that the user edited the question, but I'm not sure of the best way to do this.

I was going to add a `last_edited` column in the table (because thats all thats really important to me), but I'm not sure if I should just split the edit times (and whatever else) into another table and record everytime the question gets edited.

**EDIT:**  UIf I were to use a timestamp, what time would be used? Is there any way to insert a unix timestmap on update?

Comment: what's wrong with inserting unix timestmap on update? don't you have a function in your server-side language that returns timestamp? okay, mysql has unix_timestamp() for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all what you want is a mark Edited or not, you can just add a Timestamp column in the same table, populated to `NULL` by default, then populated by last update timestamp.

On the page if its populated then display its value, otherwise don't display the Edited icon/symbol.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on whether anyone (users or admins) ever cares about history of edits.

If they do, definitely split into another table

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about when the most recent update occurred, add a `timestamp` column in the same table.

If you'd like to keep track of every edit that's occurred, create a separate table that contains `question_id` and the `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're processing your date/time data, you can either store the unix time stamp (`fieldname = unix_timestamp(now())`), or as a regular mysql datetime field (`fieldname=now()`).

If you're going to do data sorting/filtering based on dates/times in mysql, then use the native datetime type so you can take direct advantage of all of mysql's date&time processing functions. If you're going to do most of the processing in your application, a unix timestamp tends to be more portable than a formatted date/time string.

As for the table structure, the simplest way to track edits is a pair of fields (lastedited, and lasteditor). If you want to keep a full list of editors and times, then you'll need a seperate table. If you're keeping track of the changes, then the versioning/trakcing information can go into the same table.